# Can we use IsChanged in ProcessBuilder to check if the record is new ? If not how do we check?

Tags: process-builder

I only want to trigger process builder if the record in new not on edit.
And criteria should be :Conditions are met.

---->field ischanged false

Comment: Have you tried [`ISNEW()`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the object on which the Process Builder has to act, the default option is: only when a record is created.

Is this not sufficient for you?

Comment: I have other conditions too in the PB, so I can't do that.

Comment: @sushmitabista Then you should add more detail to the question, because as it stands now, I have answered your question. But apparently your problem is more complicated than what you describe now.